# Is $d\mu = g\, dm$ a Radon measure for $g \in L^{1}(dm)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $m$ is the standard Lebesgue measure and let $g \in L^{1}(dm)$. We know that $m$ is a Radon measure. Is $\mu$ defined by $d\mu = g\, dm$ also a Radon measure?

We first claim that $\mu(K) < \infty$ for all compact $K$. We have $$\mu(K) = \int_{X}\chi_{K}\, d\mu = \int_{K}g\, dm \leq \int_{K}|g|\, dm < \|g\|_{L^{1}} < \infty.$$ But how would I show outer and inner regularity?

Comment: Is $g \ge 0$? ${}{}$

Comment: In the concrete case given here, this is easy, because **every** locally finite measure on $\Bbb{R}^d$ is Radon. This follows because every open set is $\sigma$-compact. (c.f. for example Rudin or Folland). But one can also prove it directly using regularity of $m$. Hint: Show and use that for each $\epsilon >0$ there is $\delta >0$ with $\int_E |f| dm < \epsilon$ as soon as $m(E) < \delta$.